# angular-chart cannot recognize value with thousands separator

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, angular-chart, angular-datatables

I used the Format value of MySQL because i cant add the thousand separator on angular-datatables. the problem is that the angular-chart doesn't recognize the values after the separator of y-axis as you can see on the picture.

[image: Display of Y axis]

Here is some part of my angular-chart code :

```
$scope.chart_options = {
   legend: {
      display: true
   },
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         stacked: false,
         beginAtZero: true,
         ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            autoSkip: false
         }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
         beginAtZero: true,
         ticks: {
            min: 0,
            userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
               value = value.toString();
               value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
               value = value.join(',');
               return value;
            }
         }
      }]
   }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize the values"? Are you expecting the y axis to have decimal numbers? The ticks are just skipping by a number that makes most sense for all your data, which in this case is 5. The bars are still going to the correct decimal number height. 44.635 is a drop less than 45. Do you want 44,635, because then you should format your number as `44,635.43` instead of `44.635,43`?

Comment: I used the dot because of the internationalization wherein dot is referred as thousands. but i got the idea why it didnt recognize since the ticks count the dot as a decimal. thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i got is to format the numbers in Ajax rather than in mysql